# How to stitch two images after calculating their homography

Tags: c++, opencv, orb

I am trying to stitch two overlapping images in opencv c++. I used ORB for feature matching and I calculated Homography between two images. Now using this Homography matrix I would like to go further to add two Images. But I don't know how to go further. Can any one please tell me the next steps.
Code I had written till now is:

```
detector->detect(img1, kp1,descriptors_img1);
detector->detect(img2, kp2,descriptors_img2);


Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = ORB::create();
extractor->compute(img1, kp1, descriptors_img1 );
extractor->compute(img2, kp2, descriptors_img2 );

if ( descriptors_img1.empty() )
    cvError(0,"MatchFinder","1st descriptor empty",__FILE__,__LINE__);
if ( descriptors_img2.empty() )
    cvError(0,"MatchFinder","2nd descriptor empty",__FILE__,__LINE__);
descriptors_img1.convertTo(descriptors_img1, CV_32F);
descriptors_img2.convertTo(descriptors_img2, CV_32F);
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_img1,descriptors_img2,matches);
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist )
        min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist )
        max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    {
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
    }
}
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good_matches,img_matches,Scalar::all(-1),
        Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(),DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
//-- Localize the object
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;
for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( kp1[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( kp2[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
```

Comment: Chapters 9 and 10 of Richard Szilesk's "Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications" should give you enough information how to do it. Basically you need to transform the coordinates of all the pixels of one of the two images into the others. Usually you have only a portion of the two images overlapping so the resulting image will be larger in order to include both. You can calculate the new width and height based on the corners of both images.

Comment: with warpImage you can bring both images to the same coordinate system, but you'll have to decide which pixel of which image to choose for the result. Typically this is done with some blending mechanism like alpha-blending / linear crossblending but in the end depends on the homogenity of your images (brightness, motion parallaxis, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calculating the homography matrix, you just need to warp the images and blend them together. This can be done with the `warpPerspective` function as follows.

```
cv::Mat result;

warpPerspective( img1, result, H, cv::Size( img1.cols+img2.cols, img1.rows) );
cv::Mat half(result, cv::Rect(0, 0, img2.cols, img2.rows) );
img2.copyTo(half);
```

The result is your final stitched image. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That is a great way to do it with one thing to note. By doing a warpPerspective only you will make it so the stitched images are order dependent. This means that if you try to reverse the order of the two images only one will appear. To correct for this you simply have to calculate the additional homography (lets call it htr) that needs to be mapped. This means you will have two warp perspectives. one with warpPerspective(htr) and one warpPerspective(homography*htr)

Comment: I tried the above code,but when i'm printing the result, the output is only img2 but not stitched image of img1 and img2.

Comment: Since you have not shown your image, I would recommend try swapping `img1` with `img2` and then running the whole code.

Comment: I tried swapping img2 with img1 and vice versa in the above solution which you have provided. Now the result is only img1 but not stitched image